# Better way of centering icon within CSS circle

Tags: html, css

I have a symbol inside a circle div.

http://jsfiddle.net/uqbujck3/

Is this the best way of doing this? I've heard it may be `unreliable`.

```css
.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 48px;
    padding: 0;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #1588cb;
    color: #1588cb;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 300;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a href="#" class="circle">A</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Other than really rounded corners how is this different than any other div with text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the same with a div text-align but you can use transform for perfect align.
Please try:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".circle").animate({
  width:'200px',
  height:'200px'
 },2000)
})
```

```css
.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 48px;
    padding: 0;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #1588cb;
    color: #1588cb;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 300;
    position:relative;

}
.a-text{
    position: absolute;
    text-decoration:none;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circle">
    <a href="#" class="a-text">A</a>
</div>
```